# Export a CSV file starting from a specific row

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have an SQL Query which I'm exporting to a .CSV using PowerShell, but I would like to point to a specific row to start writing the data. For example, I want to start at row number 4, and in this case lines 1, 2, 3 would be empty.

Part of my code:

`$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | export-csv -Delimiter $delimiter -Path "E:\Excel\Folder\MyFile.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-11--create-calculated-properties-for-each-inputobject) with the `-Skip` parameter:

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) | Select-Object -Skip 3 |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter -Path "E:\Excel\Folder\MyFile.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

`-Skip` would be skipping the first 3 objects in this case.

Comment: Not worked. Actually, nothing happened with this new command. Any other tip?

Comment: @user2287892 This is what you where piping to `Export-Csv` on your question so, you're saying what you currently have in your question is not working either

Comment: Adding | Select-Object -Skip 3 | to my command is not causing any effect. The .csv is still exporting without skipping the first 3 rows, for example.

Comment: @user2287892 whats the output from `$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)` ? If you remove the pipe to `Export-Csv` what do you see on the console?

Comment: $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$DataSet.Tables[0]
Output:
4796


wdd_timestamp          : 3/17/2022 1:45:25 AM
Modelo                 : XXXXXXXXX
XXXXXX              : XXXXXXXXX